# How to not show command in jenkins stage logs for shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What determines the header of stage logs in jenkins for shell scripts? Sometimes I see only `Shell Script` and some times I see `Shell Script - my command`. Is there a way to force it so that it does not show my command in header? I tried using label (`sh script: 'my-command' label:'my-label'` but it is shown as `Shell Script - my-label - my-command`).

For example in screenshot below, I don't wan to show `git rev-parse HEAD`.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of stage logs]

Comment: Are those `sh` steps created by you or wrapped inside other methods you are invoking?

Comment: `sh` steps are created by me.